# Why was Vardhamana the last Tirthankara recorded in history?

Tags: rebirth

Why has there been no Tirthankara such as Mahavira to have been born since?   Is one expected? How do we know if we have or have not entered a period when a 25th, or a 1st new Tirthankara is or has been born, or walks amongst us? thank you

Comment: Welcome to HSE! This looks like a question related to Jainism. And hence off-topic for this site. Please, correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not qualified to answer if your reply is one way or another.  I am an avid learner of many things it seems, yet ignorant of most things as they relate to a particular Scripture's Origin.  I appreciate your having taken the time to help me.  dharma